# Postgres how to get column data types for a view

Tags: postgresql

I want to get meta information of a view in postgres. Specifically the column data types. Any suggestion for how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'my_view';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following query:

```
SELECT attname AS column_name, format_type(atttypid, atttypmod) AS data_type
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'your_schema.table_or_view_name'::regclass
-- AND    NOT attisdropped
-- AND    attnum > 0
ORDER  BY attnum;
```

As query on `information_schema.columns` will show `citext` and other extension based types as `USER-DEFINED` while the following query will show the correct type e.g. `citext`.